# How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?

Tags: java, generics

I have a List which is declared like this :

```
 List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I tried to add 3 to foo3. However I get an  error message like this:

```
The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Number) in the type List<capture#1-of ?
extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (ExtendsNumber)
```

Comment: Note that `List<? extends Number>` does not mean "list of objects of different types, all of which extend `Number`". It means "list of objects of a _single_ type which extends `Number`".

Comment: You better check PECS rule, Producer extends, Consumer super. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: List<? extends Number> temp= Arrays.asList(3);

Answer (score 361, accepted):

*Sorry, but you can't.*

The wildcard declaration of `List<? extends Number> foo3` means that the variable `foo3` can hold any value from a family of types (rather than any value of a specific type). It means that any of these are legal assignments:

```
List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>();  // Number "extends" Number
List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Integer extends Number
List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Double>();  // Double extends Number
```

So, given this, what type of object could you add to `List foo3` that would be legal after any of the above possible `ArrayList` assignments:

- You can't add an `Integer` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Double>`.
- You can't add a `Double` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Integer>`.
- You can't add a `Number` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Integer>`.

**You can't add any object to `List<? extends T>` because you can't guarantee what kind of `List` it is really pointing to, so you can't guarantee that the object is allowed in that `List`. The only "guarantee" is that you can only read from it and you'll get a `T` or subclass of `T`.**

The reverse logic applies to `super`, e.g. `List<? super T>`. These are legal:

```
List<? super Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>(); // Number is a "super" of Number
List<? super Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Object>(); // Object is a "super" of Number
```

**You can't read the specific type T (e.g. `Number`) from `List<? super T>` because you can't guarantee what kind of `List` it is really pointing to. The only "guarantee" you have is you are able to add a value of type `T` (or any subclass of `T`) without violating the integrity of the list being pointed to.**

---

The perfect example of this is the signature for `Collections.copy()`:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

Notice how the `src` list declaration uses `extends` to allow me to pass any List from a family of related List types and still guarantee it will produce values of type T or subclasses of T. But you cannot add to the `src` list.

The `dest` list declaration uses `super` to allow me to pass any List from a family of related List types and still guarantee I can write a value of a specific type T to that list. But it cannot be guaranteed to read the values of **specific** type T if I read from the list.

So now, thanks to generics wildcards, I can do any of these calls with that single method:

```
// copy(dest, src)
Collections.copy(new ArrayList<Number>(), new ArrayList<Number>());
Collections.copy(new ArrayList<Number>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
Collections.copy(new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<Number>());
Collections.copy(new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<Double>());
```

---

Consider this confusing and very wide code to exercise your brain. The commented out lines are illegal and the reason why is stated to the extreme right of the line (need to scroll to see some of them):

```
  List<Number> listNumber_ListNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>();
//List<Number> listNumber_ListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();                    // error - can assign only exactly <Number>
//List<Number> listNumber_ListDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>();                     // error - can assign only exactly <Number>
  
  List<? extends Number> listExtendsNumber_ListNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>();
  List<? extends Number> listExtendsNumber_ListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<? extends Number> listExtendsNumber_ListDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>();
  
  List<? super Number> listSuperNumber_ListNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>();
//List<? super Number> listSuperNumber_ListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();      // error - Integer is not superclass of Number
//List<? super Number> listSuperNumber_ListDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>();       // error - Double is not superclass of Number
  

//List<Integer> listInteger_ListNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>();                  // error - can assign only exactly <Integer>
  List<Integer> listInteger_ListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//List<Integer> listInteger_ListDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>();                  // error - can assign only exactly <Integer>
  
//List<? extends Integer> listExtendsInteger_ListNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>(); // error - Number is not a subclass of Integer
  List<? extends Integer> listExtendsInteger_ListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//List<? extends Integer> listExtendsInteger_ListDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>(); // error - Double is not a subclass of Integer
  
  List<? super Integer> listSuperInteger_ListNumber  = new ArrayList<Number>();
  List<? super Integer> listSuperInteger_ListInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//List<? super Integer> listSuperInteger_ListDouble  = new ArrayList<Double>();     // error - Double is not a superclass of Integer


  listNumber_ListNumber.add(3);             // ok - allowed to add Integer to exactly List<Number>
  
  // These next 3 are compile errors for the same reason:
  // You don't know what kind of List<T> is really
  // being referenced - it may not be able to hold an Integer.
  // You can't add anything (not Object, Number, Integer,
  // nor Double) to List<? extends Number>      
//listExtendsNumber_ListNumber.add(3);     // error - can't add Integer to *possible* List<Double>, even though it is really List<Number>
//listExtendsNumber_ListInteger.add(3);    // error - can't add Integer to *possible* List<Double>, even though it is really List<Integer>
//listExtendsNumber_ListDouble.add(3);     // error - can't add Integer to *possible* List<Double>, especially since it is really List<Double>

  listSuperNumber_ListNumber.add(3);       // ok - allowed to add Integer to List<Number> or List<Object>
  
  listInteger_ListInteger.add(3);          // ok - allowed to add Integer to exactly List<Integer> (duh)

  // This fails for same reason above - you can't
  // guarantee what kind of List the var is really
  // pointing to
//listExtendsInteger_ListInteger.add(3);   // error - can't add Integer to *possible* List<X> that is only allowed to hold X's
  
  listSuperInteger_ListNumber.add(3);      // ok - allowed to add Integer to List<Integer>, List<Number>, or List<Object>
  listSuperInteger_ListInteger.add(3);     // ok - allowed to add Integer to List<Integer>, List<Number>, or List<Object>
```

Comment: Why are we allowed to write a sentence like  ` List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`  if we can't an element to this list further?

Comment: @articlestack: Adding isn't the only useful thing to do with a list. Once a list is populated, reading from a list may be useful. Generic wildcards allows for writing  code that works generically for a family of lists, e.g. works for both List<Integer> or List<Double>. For example, look at the signature of the Collection.copy().  The `src` `List` argument uses `extends` to read from the src list, while the the `dest` `List` argument uses `super` to write to the dest list.  This allows one method that can copy from `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>` into `List<Number>` or `List<Object>`.

Comment: Bert F, sorry for a late comment. Is there a typo in your passage, "to add a value of type T (or subclass of  T)" should read (or superclass of T)?

Comment: yea, i saw it too @Vortex Im not sure if it's right or I read it wrong.

Comment: @Vortex - `or subclass of  T` is correct.  For example, I cannot add a an `Object` (superclass of `Number`) to `List<? super Number> foo3` because `foo3` may have been assigned as: `List<? super Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>` (which can contain only `Number` or subclasses of `Number`).  `<? super Number>` refers to the types of `List<>`s that can be assigned to `foo3` - not the kinds of things that can be added/read from it. The kinds of things that can be added/removed from `foo3` must be things that can be added/removed from *any* kind of `List<>` that can be assigned to `foo3`.

Comment: @BertF `The only "guarantee" you have is you are able to add a value of type T (or any subclass of T) without violating the integrity of the list being pointed to.`. It already guarantees the elements put into List are T or subType of T, why compiler/JVM cannot cast the element into T when reading them out?

Comment: Your otherwise good answer is marred by several examples that won't compile, such as `List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>;` and `Collections.copy(new ArrayList<Number>(), new ArrayList<Integer());`.

Comment: @skomisa I have fixed the syntax errors I could find. If you see more of them, feel free to edit them yourself.

Comment: I read this and all the comments that follow it as, Java Generics is poorly thought out because the people who are expected to use it cannot understand it well enough to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 20):

You can't (without unsafe casts). You can only read from them.

The problem is that you don't know what exactly the list is a list of. It could be a list of any subclass of Number, so when you try to put an element into it, you don't know that the element actually fits into the list.

For example the List might be a list of `Byte`s, so it would be an error to put a `Float` into it.

Answer (score 4):

It has been confusing to me even though I read answers here, until I found the comment by Pavel Minaev:

> Note that List < ? extends Number > does not mean "list of objects of
>   different types, all of which extend Number". It means "list of
>   objects of a single type which extends Number"

After this I was able to understand BertF awesome explanation. List < ? extends Number > means ? could be of any type extending Number(Integer, Double, etc) and its **not clearified** in declaration ( List < ? extends Number > list ) that which of them it is, so when u wanna use add method its not known if the input is of the same **type** or not; what is the type at all?

So the elements of List < ? extends Number > could only be set when constructing.

Also note this: When we're using templates we are telling the compiler what type we're messing with. **T** for example holds that type for us, but not **?** does the same

I gotta say.. This is one of the dirty ones to explain/learn

Answer (score 3):

"List '<' ? extends Number> is actually an **upper bound wildcard !**

The upper-bounded wildcard says that any class that extends Number or Number itself can be used as the formal parameter type: 
The problem stems from the fact that **Java doesn’t know what type List** really is. 
It has to be an EXACT and UNIQUE Type. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead:

```
  List<Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>();      
  foo3.add(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fudge it by creating a reference to the List with a different type.

(These are the "unsafe casts" mentioned by sepp2k.)

```java
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// This will not compile
//list.add(100);

// WORKS, BUT NOT IDEAL
List untypedList = (List)list;
// It will let you add a number
untypedList.add(200);
// But it will also let you add a String!  BAD!
untypedList.add("foo");

// YOU PROBABLY WANT THIS
// This is safer, because it will (partially) check the type of anything you add
List<Number> superclassedList = (List<Number>)(List<?>)list;
// It will let you add an integer
superclassedList.add(200);
// It won't let you add a String
//superclassedList.add("foo");
// But it will let you add a Float, which isn't really correct
superclassedList.add(3.141);
// ********************
// So you are responsible for ensuring you only add/set Integers when you have
// been given an ArrayList<Integer>
// ********************

// EVEN BETTER
// If you can, if you know the type, then use List<Integer> instead of List<Number>
List<Integer> trulyclassedList = (List<Integer>)(List<?>)list;
// That will prevent you from adding a Float
//trulyclassedList.add(3.141);

System.out.println("list: " + list);
```

Because `untypedList`, `superclassedList` and `trulyclassedList` are just references to `list`, you will still be adding elements to the original ArrayList.

You don't actually need to use `(List<?>)` in the example above, but you might need it in your code, depending on the type of `list` you were given.

Note that using `?` will give you compiler warnings, until you put this above your function:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I have a special case where my code semantics guarantee that the cast is safe. I just needed the Java compiler to stop raising an error...

Answer (score 0):

Because 3 is `primitive (int)`, which does not extend `Number`, you can add its boxed type `(Integer.valueOf(3))`. Although it is displayed as an error in `IDEA`, it can still execute normally.