# Java generics - ArrayList initialization

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

It is known that arraylist init. should be like this

```
ArrayList<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Number>(); // compile-time error
```

so, why does java allow these ?

```
1. ArrayList<? extends Object> a1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
2. ArrayList<?> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

then, if they are correct why doesn't allow these ?

```
1. a1.add(3);
2. a2.add(3);
```

the compiler message is : The method add(int, capture#1-of ? extends Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (int)

more general

```
  1. a1.add(null e);
  2. a2.add(? e);
```

I read about this but it is good to hear from you. thanks

the other amusing point is :

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>(); // correct
 ArrayList<?> a = new ArrayList<?>(); // wrong. I know it's reason but I have some 
question in my mind that mentioned above
```

Comment: Can you do something like `a1.add(new Integer(3));`?

Comment: @Gabe you can only do a1.add(null). a1.add(3) should be cast to Integer object but compiler only see this for 2. .add(? e) and only add(null) allowed here

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add to  List<? extends Number> data structures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't assign a `List<Number>` to a reference of type `List<Integer>` because `List<Number>` allows types of numbers other than `Integer`. If you were allowed to do that, the following would be allowed:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
numbers.add(1.1); // add a double
List<Integer> ints = numbers;
Integer fail = ints.get(0); // ClassCastException!
```

The type `List<Integer>` is making a guarantee that anything it contains will be an `Integer`. That's why you're allowed to get an `Integer` out of it without casting. As you can see, if the compiler allowed a `List` of another type such as `Number` to be assigned to a `List<Integer>` that guarantee would be broken.

Assigning a `List<Integer>` to a reference of a type such as `List<?>` or `List<? extends Number>` is legal because the `?` means "some unknown subtype of the given type" (where the type is `Object` in the case of just `?` and `Number` in the case of `? extends Number`).

Since `?` indicates that you *do not know* what specific type of object the `List` will accept, it isn't legal to add anything but `null` to it. You are, however, allowed to *retrieve* any object from it, which is the purpose of using a `? extends X` bounded wildcard type. Note that the opposite is true for a `? super X` bounded wildcard type... a `List<? super Integer>` is "a list of some unknown type that is at least a supertype of `Integer`". While you don't know exactly what type of `List` it is (could be `List<Integer>`, `List<Number>`, `List<Object>`) you do know for sure that whatever it is, an `Integer` can be added to it.

Finally, `new ArrayList<?>()` isn't legal because when you're creating an instance of a paramterized class like `ArrayList`, you have to give a *specific* type parameter. You could really use whatever in your example (`Object`, `Foo`, it doesn't matter) since you'll never be able to add anything but `null` to it since you're assigning it directly to an `ArrayList<?>` reference.

Answer (score 9):

The key lies in the differences between references and instances and what the reference can promise and what the instance can really do.

```
ArrayList<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Here `a` is a reference to an instance of a specific type - exactly an array list of `A`s.  More explicitly, `a` is a reference to an array list that will accept `A`s and will produce `A`s.  `new ArrayList<A>()` is an instance of an array list of `A`s, that is, an array list that will accept `A`s and will produce `A`s.

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Here, `a` is a reference to exactly an array list of `Integers`, i.e. exactly an array list that can accept `Integer`s and will produce `Integer`s.  It cannot point to an array list of `Number`s.  That array list of `Number`s can not meet all the promises of `ArrayList<Integer> a` (i.e. an array list of `Number`s may produce objects that are not `Integer`s, even though its empty right then).

```
ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Here, declaration of `a` says that `a` will refer to exactly an array list of `Number`s, that is, exactly an array list that will accept `Number`s and will produce `Number`s.  It cannot point to an array list of `Integer`s, because the type declaration of `a` says that `a` can accept any `Number`, but that array list of `Integer`s cannot accept just any `Number`, it can only accept `Integer`s.

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> a= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Here `a` is a (generic) reference to a **family of types** rather than a reference to a specific type. It can point to any list that is member of that family.  However, the trade-off for this nice flexible reference is that they cannot promise all of the functionality that it could if it were a type-specific reference (e.g. non-generic).  In this case, `a` is a reference to an array list that will *produce* `Object`s. *But*, unlike a type-specific list reference, this `a` reference cannot *accept* any `Object`.  (i.e. not every member of the family of types that `a` can point to can accept any `Object`, e.g. an array list of `Integer`s can only accept `Integer`s.)

```
ArrayList<? super Integer> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Again, `a` is a reference to a family of types (rather than a single specific type).  Since the wildcard uses `super`, this list reference can accept `Integer`s, but it cannot produce `Integer`s. Said another way, we know that any and every member of the family of types that `a` can point to can accept an `Integer`.  However, not every member of that family can produce `Integer`s.

*PECS* - Producer `extends`, Consumer `super` - This mnemonic helps you remember that using  `extends` means the generic type can *produce* the specific type (but cannot accept it). Using `super` means the generic type can *consume* (accept) the specific type (but cannot produce it).

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> a
```

An array list that holds references to any list that is a member of a family of array lists types.

```
= new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>(); // correct
```

An instance of an array list that holds references to any list that is a member of a family of array lists types.

```
ArrayList<?> a
```

An reference to any array list (a member of the family of array list types).

```
= new ArrayList<?>()
```

`ArrayList<?>` refers to any type from a family of array list types, but you can only instantiate a specific type.

---

See also [How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures/2777297#2777297)

Answer (score 2):

You have strange expectations. If you gave the chain of arguments that led you to them, we might spot the flaw in them. As it is, I can only give a short primer on generics, hoping to touch on the points you might have misunderstood.

`ArrayList<? extends Object>` is an ArrayList whose type parameter is known to be `Object` or a subtype thereof. (Yes, extends in type bounds has a meaning other than *direct subclass*). Since only reference types can be type parameters, this is actually equivalent to `ArrayList<?>`.

That is, you can put an `ArrayList<String>` into a variable declared with `ArrayList<?>`. That's why `a1.add(3)` is a compile time error. `a1`'s declared type permits `a1` to be an `ArrayList<String>`, to which no `Integer` can be added.

Clearly, an `ArrayList<?>` is not very useful, as you can only insert null into it. That might be why the Java Spec [forbids](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9) it:

> It is a compile-time error if any of
>   the type arguments used in a class
>   instance creation expression are
>   wildcard type arguments

`ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` in contrast is a functional data type. You can add all kinds of ArrayLists into it, and retrieve them. And since `ArrayList<?>` only *contains* but *is not* a wildcard type, the above rule does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this has to do with polymorphism.  When you assign

```
X = new Y();
```

X can be much less 'specific' than Y, but not the other way around.  X is just the handle you are accessing Y with, Y is the real instantiated thing,

You get an error here because Integer is a Number, but Number is not an Integer.

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Number>(); // compile-time error
```

As such, any method of X that you call must be valid for Y.  Since X is more generally it probably shares some, but not all of Y's methods.  Still, any arguments given must be valid for Y.

In your examples with add, an int (small i) is not a valid Object or Integer.

```
ArrayList<?> a = new ArrayList<?>();
```

This is no good because you can't actually instantiate an array list containing ?'s.   You can declare one as such, and then damn near anything can follow in `new ArrayList<Whatever>();`

Answer (score 0):

Think of the `?` as to mean `"unknown"`. Thus, `"ArrayList<? extends Object>"` is to say "an unknown type that (or as long as it)extends Object". Therefore, needful to say, `arrayList.add(3)` would be putting something you know, into an unknown. I.e 'Forgetting'.

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Does not work because the fact that Number is a super class of Integer does not mean that `List<Number>` is a super class of `List<Integer>`. Generics are removed during compilation and do not exist on runtime, so parent-child relationship of collections cannot be be implemented: the information about element type is simply removed.

```
ArrayList<? extends Object> a1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
a1.add(3);
```

I cannot explain why it does not work. It is really strange but it is a fact. Really syntax `<? extends Object>` is mostly used for return values of methods. Even in this example `Object o = a1.get(0)` is valid.

```
ArrayList<?> a = new ArrayList<?>()
```

This does not work because you cannot instantiate list of unknown type...

Comment: "Really syntax `<? extends Object>` is mostly used for return values of methods." Methods should almost never return a generic type with a wildcard type parameter. Wildcard type parameters are primarily for use with the parameters of methods.