# <? extends A> won't accept A's child classes

Tags: java, android, arraylist, extends

I'm working with Android Studio and I keep getting a problem I don't know how to solve. I don't know whether it's a problem with Android Studio, with Java or a mistake a make.

I have a class whose constructor is the following:

```
public MakeQuery(Callable<ArrayList<? extends A>) {
     ...
}
```

I try to create an object of that class with the following lines:

```
Callable<ArrayList<B>> callable = new Callable<ArrayList<B>>() {...};
MakeQuery makeQuery = new MakeQuery(callable);
```

(Of course, class `B` extends `A`. Double checked)

But when I call the constructor the IDE tells me that it expects another type of argument.

What mistake am I making? Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: show all code of `Callable` class

Comment: Does the IDE tell you or the java compiler ?

Comment: The IDE tells me. I don't get to compile. And by the way, Callable is an interface that exists since JDK v 1.5. Thanks for helping!

Comment: you may try `Callable<ArrayList<? extends A>> callable = new Callable<ArrayList<? extends A>>() {...};`

Comment: It may work but that's not what I wanted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write `Callable<? extends ArrayList<? extends A>>`.

The reasons for this are complicated, but the code you wrote will only work if you pass in *exactly* `Callable<ArrayList<? extends A>>`.

The rule is that even if `B` extends `A`, `Foo<B>` does not extend `Foo<A>`.  It does, however, extend `Foo<? extends A>`.

So apply that rule twice:

1. `List<B>` doesn't extend `List<A>`, but it extends `List<? extends A>`.
2. `Callable<List<B>>` doesn't extend `Callable<List<? extends A>>`, but it extends `Callable<? extends List<? extends A>>`.

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained the reason. Even if it is complicated, it's better than "seeming to work."

Comment: I agree with that. I'd love to know why this happens.

Comment: The accepted answer here explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492950/java-generics-arraylist-initialization

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: The reason for this is particularly complicated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: That's some complex stuff! I guess I'll have to re-read it some times. Thanks for all the help!