# Dynamically initializing subclass ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way to do the following in Java?

I want to initialize an `ArrayList` based on a string value. Here the string value will definitely be one of the subclass names. I'm aware of using the `Class< T >` type to initialize an `ArrayList` of any type. But the catch is, the initialized list should be of type `List< ? extends ParentClass >`. Is there a way to use the `Class< T >` along with the `< ? extends ParentClass >` ?

```
class A{
    String s;
}

class B extends A{
    String b;
}

class D extends A{
    String d;
}

class C{
    List<? extends A> valueList;

    public C(String s){
         //The string s decides if the list is of type B or type C.
         if(type B){
             this.valueList = new ArrayList<type B>();
         }
         else{
             this.valueList = new ArrayList<type D>();
         }
    }
}
```

EDIT: As the '< >' takes the class name, I want to convert the String value to pass it in the ArrayList< >. I'm not sure to what type should I convert the String value to.

Comment: You could probably make this work, but it is totally pointless because of *type erasure*. For the first part, `s.equals("B")` should do it. But for the second, Java generics are a compile time type checking mechanism.

Comment: Something tells me that `List<? extends A> valueList;` may not be what you are really looking for. How are you planning to use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generics - ArrayList initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492950/java-generics-arraylist-initialization)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, yes I can handle it using the 'if' case. But I want it to be as concise as possible. As the '< >' takes the class name, I want to convert the String value to pass it in the ArrayList< >.

Comment: *I want to convert the String value to pass it in the ArrayList< >* You can't do that. And even if you could, it would be pointless. As I already said. Compile time checker. Not runtime.