# Why cannot I create generic arraylist member of generic class?

Tags: java, class, generics, arraylist, collections

I want to add methods to return the list or particular element and I want it to work with any generic class. Why isnt Java allowing this?

```
class ArrayListBuilder<E>{
    private ArrayList<E> a_list=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Your code works fine, it can be compiled and used. What is the problem you have?

Comment: See if this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492950/java-generics-arraylist-initialization

Comment: @Progman that *is* an MVC. You can't go any more minimal, verifiable and complete than that. The actual problem with that question is that OP doesn't say what happens with that code other than a generic "java isn't allowing this".

Comment: My code is throwing an error E cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @SamratDas you're missing an import for `java.util.ArrayList`. That's the only way you could get the error you say you're getting with your code. Also, you should read *all* of the error messages, not just the last one.

Comment: Yeah thanks that was the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to compile your code and got these errors

```
ArrayListBuilder.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
    private ArrayList<E> a_list=new ArrayList<>();
            ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class ArrayListBuilder<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayListBuilder
ArrayListBuilder.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
    private ArrayList<E> a_list=new ArrayList<>();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class ArrayListBuilder<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class ArrayListBuilder
2 errors
```

As you can see there actually are *two* errors, the first one meaning that you need to import `java.util.ArrayList`. Once you do that, your code compiles fine. So put in the first line of your code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

TL;DR: the solution to your problem is reading *all* of the error messages. Not just the last one.