# Compiler errors with java bounded wildcard generics

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

Having the below code:

```
    Stack<Integer> integers = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<? extends Number> numbers = integers;
    Number n = numbers.pop();
    numbers.push(3);
    numbers.push(n);
```

I get compilation errors on the last two lines, but although I've given it some thought I don't understand why the compilation errors are there.

```
The method push(capture#2-of ? extends Number) in the type Stack<capture#2-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

When I comment the last line, I still get the above compilation error, but from my understanding the compiler should be able to infer the correct type (Stack) from those lines.

Thanks a lot

Comment: please check the other questions at SO, there are **lots** of similar questions to this one.

Comment: I've searched through 5-10 of them and they seem to be about how to cast List<? extends Number> to List<Integer> and similar. I'll go and have a closer look though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very clear answer here
[How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

Comment: well sometimes is easier to redirect to an already existing well documented response. please give credit to that response :)

Comment: alos guys from here that spend their time to help you more then me...deserve that :)

Answer (score 2):

The last two lines aren't valid because `numbers` could be a stack of *any* numeric type. Consider this similar code:

```
Stack<Double> doubles = new Stack<Double>();
Stack<? extends Number> numbers = doubles;
Number n = numbers.pop();
numbers.push(3);
numbers.push(n);
```

Here you're trying to put an `Integer` onto a `Stack<Double>` which obviously isn't correct.

Basically when you use wildcarding like this, you can get values *out*, but you can't put values *in* because the compiler can't guarantee it's valid to do so.

Comment: From reading this and the link provided by @Cris I seem to understand the problem at hand. However, why can't the compiler infer the type, when there is only one element (of type Integer) pushed onto the stack?

Comment: @yas4891: The compiler isn't *meant* to infer anything from the previous lines of code - only from the type of the variable, which is `Stack<? extends Number>`.

Answer (score 2):

Generics covariance in Java is handled at the client. i.e. You don't have the semantics to say that a Stack is covariant and let the compiler check that the operations you are allowing (like push) is valid in a covariance model. (push is not).

The specific issue here is that you can do something like this:

```
Number r = new Rational(a,b); // rationals are also numbers
number.push(r);
```

which in the underlying structure implies integer.push(r); // type mismatch

(Programming in Scala has a crystal clear explanation of client vs provider side (co-/contra-)variance on Chapter 19. A recommended read even if you are not into Scala)