# Generics: suggest correct syntax

Tags: java

1. `List<String>[] stringList = new List<?>[10];`
   gives `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<?>[] to List<String>[]`
2. If i use following statement
   `List<? extends Number> inLi = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
   then `inLi. inLi.add(5);` gives `The method add(int, capture#1-of ? extends Number) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Number> is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: 1. `List<List<String>> stringsList = new ArrayList<>();` 2. `Lint<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();`. Or prior to  Java SE 7: 1. `List<List<String>> stringsList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();` 2. `Lint<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 1 doesn't work, because `List<String>[]` means an array of String lists, while `List<?>[]` means an array of lists of anything. In a `List<String>[]` array, you can not have a `List<Integer>` element, but `List<?>[]` could have an element that's a `List<Integer>`, hence the type mismatch error.

In short, in Java it is not possible to create a generic array like this:

```
Foo<T>[] fooArray = new Foo<T>[];
```

But you can create a generic array like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // optional but informs the compiler 
                               // not to generate warning message
List<String>[] stringList = new ArrayList[10];
```

For more information see [this](http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node181.html).

Regarding 2, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures).

Comment: Could you plz tell alternate solution/statement for problem 1.

Comment: I am using List<String>[] stringList = (List<String>[]) new List<?>[10]; for 1st problem. Whether it is good?