# Insert into generic Number ArrayList Java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method:

```
  private <E extends Number> void AddOne(ArrayList<E> al, Double num) {
      al.add(num);
  }
```

al.add(num) doesn't work. What is the best way I can insert a number into a generic Number Array?

So basically, I have a generic

> ArrayList< E > al

And I want to insert a numeric value in it, how can I do this? (I remember C++ being a lot easier -_-)

Comment: Doesn't work means? What you are expecting and what you got? Without those details it is hard to answer any question.

Comment: Your `ArrayList` is a list of E's, so what you can insert in it must be an E or a subclass. `Double` is a `Number`, but it isn't necessarily an E; you'd have to cast it to an E for this to work. Is this really the signature you need?

Comment: What about ArrayList<Number> without "extends"?

Comment: Answers: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java  2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add anythig to this list, because you don't know what type it really is.

Consider inheritance tree like this:

```
Number
|
|- BigInteger
            |
            |- NonNegativeInteger
                                |
                                |-PositiveInteger
```

You say that your list is list of elements which inherits from `Number`. Ok, so suppose you want to add `Number` to a list, but wait you could have `List<BigInteger>` and you cannot put `Number` into it.

Ok, so you could put `BigInteger`, right? No! Because your list could be `List<NonNegativeInteger>`. And the story goes on and on...

Declaring list as `List<T extends SomeObject>` ensures you that when you get something from list it's of type `SomeObject`. Nothing else is known.

So how to avoid the problem? Just remove the template.

```
List<Number>
```

And now you can put anything what inherites from `Number`.

Or, what is even better in your case, change `Double` to `E`:

```
private <E extends Number> void AddOne(ArrayList<E> al, E num) {
  al.add(num);
}
```

Comment: +1 for good explanation, and as a side note, you could use ArrayList<? super Number> al and then use it to store Numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your add to:

```
  private <E extends Number> void AddOne(ArrayList<E> al, E num) {
      al.add(num);
  }
```

and then in any concrete instance of your generic class, where `E` resolves to a specific number class, you'll be able to add numbers of that type.

Answer (score 2):

Your method makes no sense. You want to add a `Double` to an `ArrayList` that is defined as holding any class that extends `Number`.

What happens if the array you pass in is `ArrayList<Integer>` and you try and add your `Double` to it?

If you're only interested in having an `ArrayList` that holds things that are subclasses of `Number`, you don't need generics in your method; simply use an `ArrayList<Number>`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
 private void AddOne(ArrayList<Number> al, Double num) {
      al.add(num);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you really want is:

```
private void AddOne(ArrayList<Number> al, Double num) {
     al.add(num);
}
```

Otherwise you can't add anything to the List with adding the cast to E