# Java Generics for Upper bound & lower bound wild cards

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard

I was reading java generics, I came across an interesting query. My question is as follows.

1. For an upper bounded wildcard

   ```
   public static void printList(List<? extends Number> list) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           list.add(i);// gives compilation error
       }
   }
   ```
2. For a lower bounded wildcard

   ```
   public static void printList(List<? super Integer> list) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           list.add(i);// successfully compiles
       }
   }
   ```

I am confused with this because looking at the Sun Oracle documentation I understand that the code should compile for point 1 as well

[Upper Bound Wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)
[Lower Bound Wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)

Can anyone please help me to understand this?

Comment: @baraky: thanks for the link I missed it somehow.. but still the question is why does it not compile when the Generic type knows that it has to be a class extended by Number. Sorry for redundant question. It is still unclear for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because when you are using upper bound, you cannot add elements to collection, only read them.

this means that these are some of legal assignments:

```
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

so you cannot guarantee that when adding object, it will hold correct types of objects. for better explatation please follow:
[How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

Answer (score 2):

actually, fortunately the same scenario, I got the answer under next pages of Sun Oracle documentation. please find the link below. may be useful to someone who would be searching in future.

[Wildcard Capture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)