# Error While Passing Bounded Wild Card Collection in Java

Tags: java, generics

For the below Class Structure:

```
class BaseClass{}
   class A extends BaseClass{}
   class B extends BaseClass{}
```

I have this method in main:

```
public static void goThroughMap(Map<String,Collection<? extends BaseClass>> myMap) {}
```

Now to call this method , i am doing something like:

```
Map<String,Collection<B>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
goThroughMap(myMap); // is causing a compile time error
```

The error is:

```
The method goThroughMap(Map<String,Collection<? extends BaseClass>>)  is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,Collection<B>>)
```

So, how should i modify my method parameters to make this work?
Any pointers for further reading are welcome.

I have seen related questions by other users(see links below), but none of them seem solve the issue here:

1. [PECS in generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)
2. [Upper and Lower Bound Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189229/java-generics-for-upper-bound-lower-bound-wild-cards)

Comment: Please show how have you declared `B`.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following declaration for your method :

```
public static void goThroughMap(Map<String,? extends Collection<? extends BaseClass>> myMap)
```

You can refer to this link for more details on such types :
[Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ104)

Comment: This works for me. Going through the link to understand more about this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generify your method properly:

```
public static <T extends BaseClass> void goThroughMap(Map<String, Collection<T>> myMap) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you point out what exactly is wrong with my declarations. Both your and Scrooge McD's answers work for me.