# How to add items to a generic list of the same supertype?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to have a method in one of my services that should return a generic list.
Then I want to add items to that list from another service.

```
class Fruit;
class Apple extends Fruit;

class FruitService() {
        private ArrayList<? extends Fruit> getList() {
            return new ArrayList<Apple>();
        }
}

class SomeService() {
        init() {
            fruitService.getList().add(new Apple());
        }
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
The method add(capture#3-of ? extends Fruit) in the type ArrayList<capture#3-of ? extends Fruit> is not applicable for the arguments (Apple)
```

Why? How could I add an Apple to that generic list?

My goal is to have that getList() method not to return a specific implementation.

Comment: whats wrong with returning ArrayList<Fruit>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

```
ArrayList<? extends Fruit>
```

could be in fact an

```
ArrayList<Apple>
```

in which you can't insert a `Banana` although `Banana extends Fruit`. And you can't insert a `Fruit` because it has to be at least something that extends `Apple`. And since Java can't see the required type anymore but has to guarantee that it would work it won't even allow you to insert an `Apple` although that would be allowed for the actual list.

-> You can't insert *anything* into `List<? extends Whatever>` besides `null` because you don't know the exact type. `? extends Whatever` results in a read-only list of `Whatever`.

If you want to return a regular & useful `List` don't return one with wildcard types.

Instead you could use generics in `FruitService` e.g.

```
class FruitService<T extends Fruit> {
    private ArrayList<T> getList() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void useList(T fruit) {
        getList().add(fruit);
    }
}

class User {
    void foo() {
        FruitService<Apple> appleService = new FruitService<Apple>();
        appleService.useList(new Apple());

        FruitService<Banana> bananaService = new FruitService<Banana>();
        bananaService.useList(new Banana());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you have your `getList()` method return a `List` (or `ArrayList`) of `Fruit` instead?  That way, you can insert any subtype of `Fruit` into the `List`.

```
private List<Fruit> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<Fruit>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make the method generic -

```
public <T extends Fruit> List<T> getList() {
    //....
```

The type variable `T` can capture the actual type argument, so the compiler can assume type-safety.

Also, you can do `return new ArrayList<T>();` instead of `return new ArrayList<Apple>();`.