# Java generics inconsistent behavior?

Tags: java, generics

Why does the first method compile, and the second not? The generics for `Set` and `ImmutableSet.Builder` are the same, and the type signatures for their `add` methods are also the same.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

public class F {

    public static ImmutableSet<? extends Number> testImmutableSetBuilder() {
        ImmutableSet.Builder<? extends Number> builder = ImmutableSet.builder();
        Number n = Integer.valueOf(4);
        builder.add(n);
        return builder.build();
    }

    public static Set<? extends Number> testJavaSet() {
        Set<? extends Number> builder = new HashSet<Number>();
        Number n = Integer.valueOf(4);
        builder.add(n);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

I am using javac version 1.7.0_25 to build. I get the following error on the second method, but not on the first. I believe I should get the error in both cases, as it is not type correct to put a `Number` into a collection of `? extends Number`.

```
error: no suitable method found for add(Number)
        builder.add(n);
               ^
    method Set.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
      (actual argument Number cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
```

Comment: Both the method fails to compile on my PC as expected.

Comment: Take a look here, I believe this answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures

Comment: @Rohit, what version of SDK are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Farlan. I'm expecting both methods to fail to compile, for the reasons explained in the link you posted. What is perplexing to me is why the first example *does* compile, without warning.

Comment: The "This question may already have an answer here:" at the top of the post is definitely wrong. How do I get rid of it or vote it down?

Comment: @sullivan- I think that's only visible to you unless enough people vote to close the question. Hopefully people now see that it's not a duplicate (of that post at least).

Comment: Unfortunately, Eclipse disagrees with JDK 7 in this case, and fails to compile both of these methods.

Comment: It looks like a javac bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `add(E)` is not appliccable, but the matter is less clear for the method `add(E...)`:

The Java Language Specification [defines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4):

> The method m is an applicable variable-arity method if and only if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - For 1 ≤ i < n, the type of ei, Ai, can be converted by method invocation conversion to Si.
> - If k ≥ n, then for n ≤ i ≤ k, the type of ei, Ai, can be converted by method invocation conversion to the component type of Sn.
> - ...

In our case Sn is `capture-of-? extends Number[]`.

Now just what is the component type of Sn? Unfortunately, the JLS does not give a formal definition for that term. In particular, it not said explicitly whether the component type is a compile time type (which need not be reifiable) or a runtime type (which must be). In case of the former, the component type would be `capture-or-? extends Number`, which cannot accept a Number through method invocation conversion. In case of the latter, the component type would be `Number`, which obviously can.

It appears that the implementors of the eclipse compiler have used the former definition, while the implementors of javac have used the latter.

Two facts seem to imply that the component type is indeed a runtime type. First, the spec [requires](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.5):

> If the type of the value being assigned is not assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the component type, an ArrayStoreException is thrown.
>
> *If the component type of an array were not reifiable (§4.7), the Java Virtual Machine could not perform the store check described in the preceding paragraph. This is why an array creation expression with a non-reifiable element type is forbidden (§15.10). One may declare a variable of an array type whose element type is non-reifiable, but assignment of the result of an array creation expression to the variable will necessarily cause an unchecked warning (§5.1.9).*

and second, the runtime evaluation of a method invocation expression targeting a variable arity method is defined as follows:

> If m is being invoked with k ≠ n actual argument expressions, or, if m is being invoked with k = n actual argument expressions and the type of the k'th argument expression is not assignment compatible with T[], then the argument list (e1, ..., en-1, en, ..., ek) is evaluated as if it were written as (e1, ..., en-1, new |T[]| { en, ..., ek }), where |T[]| denotes the erasure (§4.6) of T[].

A casual reading of this paragraph might lead one to think that the expression is not just *evaluated*, but also *type checked* that way, but the specification doesn't quite say that.

On the other hand, it is quite an odd notion to use the erasure for compile time type checking (though the spec requires this in some other cases).

To summarize, the observed differences between the eclipse compiler and javac appear to stem from a slightly different interpretation of the type checking rules for non-reifiable variable-arity method arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I think I started to figure out the answer. `ImmutableSet.Builder` method `add` is overloaded, there is an alternate signature `add(E... elements)`. I ran `javap -v` on the resulting .class file and I saw that this alternative method is the one that is actually getting called. The varargs `elements` is actually a Java array under the covers, and Java arrays are covariant. I.e., in regards to this specific example, we call

```
builder.add(n);
```

The `Number n` is converted into a single-element array of type `Number[]`. But I don't know how that array is legally converted into an array of `<? extends Number>`!

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Set<? extends Number> builder;` it means it could have anything which `extends` `Number`, e.g. `Integer`. Now you are putting a `Number` in `builder.add(n);` which is not an `Integer`. If you need add something you should do `Set<? super Number> builder;`.

Comment: The question is not about how to fix the code to compile. It's about the strange behavior of the javac compiler

Answer (score 0):

There is something called GET & PUT principle. It is always recommended to follow it.

### GET & PUT principle

"use an extends wildcard when you only get values out of a structure, use a super wildcard when you only put values into a structure, and don’t use a wildcard when you both get and put"