# generic wild card covariance and arraylist add function behaviour

Tags: java, generics

`EquilateralTriangle` is a subtype of `Triangle`.

```
List<? super EquilateralTriangle> equilateralTriangle =
        new ArrayList<Triangle>(Arrays.asList(new Triangle(), new Triangle()));
equilateralTriangle.add(new Triangle());            // doesn't work
equilateralTriangle.add(new EquilateralTriangle()); // works
```

As far as I know `List<? super EquilateralTriangle>` is the declaration and with `new ArrayList<Triangle>` we are telling something concrete to the compiler that my arraylist is of type triangle. Then why does compiler complain on the second line? I'm inserting the same value as I defined in the type parameter defined while instantiating arraylist.

Java arraylist definition says this:

```
class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>

public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

and  `boolean add(E e);` for `ArrayList`.

So, the type `E` can be infered as `Triangle`. Then `add` must not complain as I'm passing the `Triangle` as I did in `ArrayList` constructor. What is missing in my understanding?

Comment: The add method's parameter is in contravariant position, I think that is the reason why it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures and several others. You can't add to that list type after you assign it; `?` means *unknown*. You're adding to a known list on line 1.

Comment: Hi Brian that is true in case of List<? extends Number> foo3 example because you don't know exactly which type and is family of the types thats what wild cards say. But I used <? super E>, if that is the case why equilateralTriangle.add(new EquilateralTriangle()); **is working**

Comment: Thanks Brain I think I got it. It worked because you are adding Triangle which is the super type of EquilateralTriangle. But how compiler knows that which super type. But as you defined ? super EquilateralTriangle that means compiler is pretty sure as you defined in declaration type parameter.Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following statements. Obviously, adding a *String* works whereas adding an *Object* causes a compile-time error.

```
List<String> items = ...;
items.add(new String()); // works
items.add(new Object()); // error
```

Now, let's use a wildcard as in your question:

```
List<? super String> items = ...;
```

In this variable declaration, the `?` stands for an *unknown type*, that is either *String* or a base class of *String*. The type is not deduced/inferred. It is just an *unknown type*. The compiler must assume, that `? super String` can be `String`. And as we have seen above, you are not supposed to add *Objects* into a list of *Strings*.

Answer (score 0):

[nosid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22580426/697449) explains the contravariance part. I'll just address this question:

> why does compiler complain on the second line? I'm inserting the same value as I defined in the type parameter defined while instantiating arraylist.

I could ask you the same question about this code:

```
Object object = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
object.add(new Triangle());
```

Why doesn't this work? Doesn't the compiler know that `object` is an `ArrayList<Triangle>`?

The answer is no. It doesn't matter to the compiler what type was instantiated. What matters is the type of the variable that you call `add` on.