# java generics: bounded wildcard upsetting eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

There is an external interface named Shape (name changed, but you get the idea).

I have a class that has a constructor that takes

```
Collection<? extends Shape>
```

This class is under test.  I am writing the unit tests.  I want to create a Collection that extends Shape to provide to the constructor.

I notice that no class in our project implements Shape, so I write an inner class:

```
private class TestShape implements Shape {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

Then I try to create my Collection ...

```
private ArrayList<? extends Shape> shapes;
shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
shapes.add(new TestShape());
```

Eclipse however is unhappy with me ...

```
The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Shape) in the type ArrayList<capture#1-of ? extends Shape> is not applicable for the arguments (Test.TestShape)
```

Why?

edit:  Lots of editing because generics syntax makes SO unhappy

Comment: This is PECS at work!

Comment: @user3580294 I'm not familiar with that abbreviation.

Comment: @hexafraction Producer Extends Consumer Super? For wildcards in generics -- if the list is producing things, you use `extends`, and if you're sticking things into the list, you use `super`.

Comment: @user3580294 May I add that to my post with attribution?

Comment: @hexafraction You could add that, but don't attribute it to me -- I first heard of it from Joshua Bloch in Effective Java. Don't know if that's where it originated from, but that's where I first learned it.

Comment: @user3580294 Thanks, I'll have to read that sometime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's imagine that we have `TestShape` implements `Shape`, and `EvilShape` also implements `Shape`. Now imagine the following:

```
private ArrayList<? extends Shape> shapes; //OK
shapes = new ArrayList<EvilShape>(); // OK
authorities.add(new TestShape()); // Type safety issue
```

Clearly, such a thing won't work. Instead, do the following:

```
private ArrayList<Shape> shapes; //OK
shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>(); // OK
authorities.add(new TestShape()); // OK
```

*Or* the following:

```
private ArrayList<? super Shape> shapes; //OK
shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>(); // Or, for that matter, an `ArrayList<Object>`.
authorities.add(new TestShape()); // OK
```

This will work, as you can add a subclass/implementation of `Shape` to a `List<Shape>`. Using an exact type parameter and not a wildcard will prevent the following:

```
private ArrayList<Shape> shapes; //OK
shapes = new ArrayList<EvilShape>(); // DANGER! Java does not allow this
```

The abbreviation **PECS** helps remember this: Producer Extends, Consumer Super. This comes from Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*.

Comment: This certainly seems to be the right answer, but I'm doing exactly this and still getting the eclipse compilation error.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had found the answer was with my Shape import, but no, that import is correct.  Still confused.

Comment: @Lurk21 What if you avoid the wildcard and just go with a basic parameter of `Shape`?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a class that has a constructor that takes
>
> ```
> Collection<? extends Shape>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Then I try to create my Collection ...
>
> ```
> private ArrayList<? extends Shape> shapes;
> ```

I think one thing that may be confusing is that just because there is a method parameter like that (`Collection<? extends Shape>`), you don't need to create a variable like that.  Think of the purpose of a variable/parameter that uses wildcard generics (? extends X or ? super Y) as a way to write some "generic" code that will work with any value from a `family of similar types` rather than the usual "a value from a specific type".

--

The perfect example of this is the signature for Collection.copy():

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest,List<? extends T> src)
```

This method allows me to pass an instance of `List<Integer>` and have its values copied into an instance of `List<Number>`.  It also allows me to copy `List<Integer>` into `List<Integer>`.  It lets me use the same code with different types ("family of types").  I can test it with using wildcard generic variables at all:

```
List<Integer> src = new ArrayList<>();
src.add(1);
List<Number> dest = new ArrayList<>();

Collection.copy(src, dest);

assert(src.get(0), dest.get(0));
```

--

**The big tradeoff with using a variable or parameter like `List<? super T>` or `List<? extends T>` is that because its not a variable for a *specific* type, there are limitations on what you can assume about the instance it points to and therefore you are limited in what you can do with it.**

`PECS` is a tiny bit of an oversimplification, but it makes a great mnemonic: `PECS` = "producer extends, consumer super" means that a variable (or parameter) for a generic wildcard type that uses `extends` can only be used to "produce" values, i.e. you can safely only read from it, you can't add to it. Similarly, a variable for a generic wildcard type that uses `super` can only be used to "consume" values - you can safely only feed it values (add), but there are limitations on what you can assume about the values that could be "read" from it.

So, for your example, I would avoid using a variable with a wildcard generic at all, just pass in different List<> types to the constructor.  If you must use a variable with a wildcard generic, that use a variable to the specific type to fill it because the variable with the wildcard generic that uses `extends` can't be used to fill it:

```
private ArrayList<Shape> shapesSpecific;
private ArrayList<? extends Shape> shapesExtends;
shapesExtends = shapesSpecific = new ArrayList<Shape>();

shapesSpecific.add(new TestShape());   // fine
//shapesExtends.add(new TestShape());  // error - but the line above added a value already

// Another option - create it already filled:
// shapeExtends = Arrays.asList(new TestShape());

new Foo(shapesSpecific);  // fine
new Foo(shapesExtends);   // fine
```

--

You might find this question/answer useful:

[How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures/2777297#2777297) - here's an example from it:

> The wildcard declaration of `List<? extends Number> foo3` means that
>   the variable `foo3` can hold any value from a family of types (rather
>   than any value of a specific type). It means that any of these are
>   legal assignments:
>
> ```
> List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>;  // Number "extends" Number
> List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>; // Integer extends Number
> List<? extends Number> foo3 = new ArrayList<Double>;  // Double extends Number
> ```
>
> So, given this, what type of object could you add to `List foo3` that
>   would be legal after any of the above possible `ArrayList`
>   assignments:
>
> - You can't add an `Integer` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Double>`.
> - You can't add a `Double` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Integer>`.
> - You can't add a `Number` because `foo3` could be pointing at a `List<Integer>`.
>
> **You can't add any object to `List<? extends T>` because you can't guarantee what kind of `List` it is really pointing to, so you can't
>   guarantee that the object is allowed in that `List`.  The only
>   "guarantee" is that you can only read from it and you'll get a `T` or
>   subclass of  `T`.**

This is a similar question/answer:

[Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java/4343547#4343547)

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a unit test, just make a collection of Shapes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class test {
    public interface Shape {
        String getAuthority();

    }

    private static class TestShape implements Shape {

        @Override
        public String getAuthority() {
            return "Foo";
        }
    }

    public static void method(Collection<? extends Shape> shapes){

    }

    public static void main(String ... args){
        ArrayList<Shape> shapes;
        shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        shapes.add(new TestShape());
        method(shapes);
    }
}
```

this compiles cleanly and is likely how the method is used in actual practice.