# Java generics: incompatible wildcard capture

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have a repository interface parameterized with stored entities type. Among other methods in it, I have two of interest: the `create()` method which instantiates an entity, and the `save()` method that saves the entity:

```
public interface INamedEntityRepository<T extends INamedEntity> {
    T create(String name);
    void save(T namedEntity);
}
...
```

Next follows a snippet of how this interface is used. I am getting a compilation error saying the type returned from the `create()` and that passed into `save()` are incompatible.

```
INamedEntityRepository<? extends INamedEntity> repo = getEntityRepository();

INamedEntity toSave = repo.create("Named");
... // configure the entity more...
repo.save(toSave);
      ^
```

`The method save(capture#7-of ? extends INamedEntity) in the type INamedEntityRepository<capture#7-of ? extends INamedEntity> is not applicable for the arguments (INamedEntity)`. I can understand this, because really `INamedEntity` is not necessarily the expected type.

But even doing this

```
repo.save(repo.create("Named")));
```

won't help:

`The method save(capture#7-of ? extends INamedEntity) in the type INamedEntityRepository<capture#7-of ? extends INamedEntity> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#8-of ? extends INamedEntity)`.

What's the problem? How to correctly handle this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter whether you store the result of `repo.create("Named")` in a variable or not, the compiler checks its type, and since the type returned by `create` is `INamedEntity`, this won't work. To fix this, the compiler has to know that `create` returns something that is a subtype of what `save` can accept, and that is exactly when you *don't* use wildcards.

In this particular case, you know of course that the types are correct, so you can use an unsafe cast like this:

```
((INamedEntityRepository<INamedEntity>) repo).save(repo.create("Named"));
```

or you can delegate the issue of the unsafe operation to another location, e.g. declare `repo` without the wildcard in the first place.

---

In case that `getEntityRepository()` actually returns some concrete type, not the wildcarded one, you could use something like this:

```
void <T extends INamedEntity> test() {
    INamedEntityRepository<T> repo = getEntityRepository();
    T toSave = repo.create("Named");
    repo.save(toSave);
}
```

Which looks pretty obvious now that I typed it out...

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to call .save on any INamedEntityRepository instance which is declared using a capturing generic definition (i.e. ? extends). This is similar to how you cannot call add on a List.

[How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know the unknown type is the *same* unknown type for both usages. The solution is to "lock" the type to a *particular* type for the two usages. If this were a method for example, you could type the method:

```
public <T extends INamedEntity> void someMethod(String name) {
    INamedEntityRepository<T> repo = getEntityRepository(); // may need cast here
    T toSave = repo.create(name);
    // do stuff with toSave
    repo.save(toSave);
}
```

You haven't shown the signature for getEntityRepository(), so a cast may be required, so if it too is a typed method, you can use the syntax:

```
INamedEntityRepository<T> repo = MyClass.<T>getEntityRepository();
```

if static, or

```
INamedEntityRepository<T> repo = this.<T>getEntityRepository();
```

if non-static, to pass the type through.

Answer (score 0):

The Silly Freak's and Bohemian's solutions with a type-locking method indeed give me a warning and make me do a cast when doing `getEntityRepository()`. So I am putting here a variant which compiles for me without any warning:

```
protected abstract INamedEntityRepository<? extends INamedEntity> getEntityRepository();
...

// the method that extracts the code of interest
private <T extends INamedEntity> void test(String name, INamedEntityRepository<T> repo) {
   T toSave = repo.create(name);
   repo.save(toSave);
}
...

test("Named", getEntityRepository());
```