# How to add items to a list of type List<? extends Object>

Tags: list, arraylist

I have a list which is of type -

```
List<? extends Object> = new ArrayList<oracle.jbo.domain.Date> ();
```

But when I try to add the items to this list I get compile time error - 
this step -

```
a.add( new oracle.jbo.domain.Date() );
```

will throw following error -

```
Error(183,22):  cannot find method add(oracle.jbo.domain.Date)
```

How to add elements to this list ?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your `ArrayList` contains `oracle.jbo.domain.Date` instances, why are you saving the reference to a `List<? extends Object>`? Using generics in reference should be avoided (as you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)) when you want to insert elements in the list. But your `ArrayList` can only contain one kind of data so:

```
List<oracle.jbo.domain.Date> a = new ArrayList<oracle.jbo.domain.Date>();
a.add( new oracle.jbo.domain.Date() );
```

But if you really have a `List<? extends Object>`, then sorry but you can't insert elements to that list. In fact the compiler has no int about which kind of list it is. This is different from:

```
List<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

In fact in that case you know you can add anything, because everything extends `Object`. But in this case any of those are legal assignments:

```
List<? extends Object> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Object> a = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<? extends Object> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and the compiler doesn't know which one is the current case. So you are prevented from inserting elements. This is commonly used to make read-only objects.

Comment: This is not an object which I am creating. When I am trying to get the list from inbuilt API from Oracle ADF framework. I have to overwrite the values within the object, when I checked the type of the objects it shows - List<? extends Object> and inside this list if I check each item all are of type jbo.domain.Date. Hence I am trying to set Date values on this list but it wouldn't allow me to. I trying to figure out how do i set the/owerwrite the date values in this list.