# Casting to generic variable

Tags: java, generics, casting

I understand generic and casting but I dont understand generic casting. I thought I can cast only to specific type up or down through inheritence tree but this proved me wrong:

```
ArrayList<?> cislo = (ArrayList<? extends Number>) new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This might not be the best example but hopefully you will get my point. How does this work? To what type its get cast?

Comment: At run time there is no cast at all, as the generic information is lost (type erasure). At compile time you tell the compiler to handle that `ArrayList<Integer>` as an `ArrayList<? extends Number>` and be quiet about it (except the warning, basically it's the same as if you'd cast a `Number` variable to `Integer` - you tell the compiler you know what you're doing). The assignment to `ArrayList<?>` works in any case.

Comment: With Generics, casting should not be necessary at all. If you feel like casting a Generic type, perhaps you should check if there is not a "clean" solution without cast just by using the huge flexibility Generics have. I am sure that many people are willung to help if you have a specific example.

Comment: I do have specific example. I work with framwork which allows to annotate JUnit test to select storage I want to send results to e.g `@ReesmoConfiguration(storage = RestApiStorage.class)` and in the abstract superclass Storage i found factory method
`newInstance(Object configuration){
Class<? extends Storage> clazz = null;
if (Bool.FALSE.equals(Property.ENABLED.get(configuration))) {
clazz = DummyStorage.class;
} else {
clazz = (Class<? extends Storage>) Property.STORAGE.get(configuration);
}
if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(DummyStorage.class)) {
return new DummyStorage();
}}`

Comment: Ok this is basically `Class<? extends Storage> clazz = (Class<? extends Storage>) Property.STORAGE.get(configuration);` - this will work if  the Object returned by `get` is the class-object of something that is a subtype of `Storage. The cast is necessary if the return type of `get` is a supertype of that (e.g. `Object` or some interface)

Answer (score 4):

The cast is unnecessary.

The assignments

```
ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<? extends Number> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

don't require any explicit casting.

Wildcard types are "more general"/"less specific" types than concrete types, and [upper bounded wildcard types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) (like `? extends Number`) are more specific than [unbounded ones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) (`?`).

More information on the relation between wildcard types can be found in the [Oracle Tutorial on Wildcards and Subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html).

The relevant part of the JLS specifying this is [4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)

> Given a generic type declaration C (n > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type C, where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a type, are all of the following:
>
> - D, where D is a generic type which is a direct supertype of the generic type C and θ is the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].
> - C, where Si contains Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) (§4.5.1).
>
> [...]

which refers to 
[4.5.1. Type Arguments of Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

> A type argument T1 is said to contain another type argument T2, written T2 <= T1, if the set of types denoted by T2 is provably a subset of the set of types denoted by T1 under the reflexive and transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping (§4.10)):
>
> - ? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S
> - ? extends T <= ?
>
> [...]

So by this definition `ArrayList<? extends Number>` is a supertype of `ArrayList<Integer>` and `ArrayList<?>` is a supertype of any `ArrayList<>` except the raw type.

Assignment to a variable of a type that is a supertype does not require casting.

---

A cast is necessary if you want to assign something of a different type:

```
Object list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//...somewhere else - the compiler does not know that list is always an ArrayList, but we tell it that we know what we are doing
List<? extends Number> numbers = (List<? extends Number>) list; //unchecked cast warning, but works
```

After that cast, you can e.g. get elements from the list and treat them as `Number`s. The cast will fail at runtime if you assign something else to the `list` reference which is not a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`

```
    Object list = new HashSet<Integer>();
    List<? extends Number> numbers = (List<? extends Number>) list; //unchecked cast warning
```

fails at runtime throwing

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.List`

---

The problems start to arise when the generic type does not match:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("hi");
Object list = stringList;
List<? extends Number> numbers = (List<? extends Number>) list; //unchecked cast warning, but (sadly) works

Number n = numbers.get(0); //fails: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

This happens because at runtime, the Erasure of the list-types matches. See also [the tutorial on erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

Comment: "The cast is unnecessary." - as I said could not be the best example. I find jls really hard to read, but your explanation really helped, thx. Additional info can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures