# incompatible types: SomeX cannot be converted to CAP#1

Tags: java, generics

I can't grasp what is wrong here

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    private static class SomeX {}

    void doSomethingWithX(SomeX someX) {
        Collection<? extends SomeX> colectionOfX = new ArrayList<>();
        colectionOfX.add(someX);
    }
}
```

`javac` says following:

> ```
>   Main.java:8: error: method add in interface Collection<E> cannot be applied to given types;
>           colectionOfX.add(someX);
>                       ^
>     required: CAP#1
>     found: SomeX
>     reason: argument mismatch; SomeX cannot be converted to CAP#1
>     where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in interface Collection
>     where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends SomeX from capture of ? extends SomeX
> ```

To my understanding `extends` limits the lower bound of CAP#1 to `SomeX` and `SomeX` itself should satisfy the limit.

What's wrong? (Compiled with `javac 1.8.0_102`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow `colectionOfX` to contain any instance of `SomeX`, it should be declared as :

```
Collection<SomeX> colectionOfX = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you declare it as

```
Collection<? extends SomeX> colectionOfX = ...;
```

it means you can assign to it any `Collection` that holds elements of some type that is either `SomeX` or a sub-class of `SomeX`.

For example, you can assign to it a `List<SomeBX>`, where `SomeBX` extends `SomeX`. In that case only instances of `SomeBX` can be added to the collection.
So if you try to add to the collection a `SomeX` instance which is not a `SomeBX` (for example, an instance of `SomeAX`, which is also a sub-class of `SomeX`), it would be invalid.

Comment: So ... all this does not answer question of "Why I can't add `instance of SomeX` into `Collection<? extends SomeX>`". What is wrong in that particular operation?

Comment: @XtraCoder As I tried to explain, `Collection<? extends SomeX> colectionOfX` doesn't accept all instances of `SomeX`. Even if you assign to it `new ArrayList<SomeX>()`, to which you should be able to add any instance of `SomeX`, the compiler can't know that, since it only relies on the compile time type, which is `Collection<? extends SomeX>`.

Answer (score 1):

So, the question is actually already answered in "[How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)", but googling just did not bring that match.

Short answer, as far as I get it, is below:

```
class Main {
    private static class SomeX {}

    private static class SomeY extends SomeX {}

    void doSomethingWithX(SomeX someX) {
        Collection<? extends SomeX> colectionOfX = new ArrayList<SomeY>();
        colectionOfX.add(someX);
    }
}
```

Because `<? extends SomeX>` is rather a lower-bound limit for Collection type than item type - it will be possible to assign instance of collection with higher-bounded value and, taking this into account, putting SomeX into such collection is not type-safe from compiler's perspective.