# Intellij idea java 8 hashmap can't find proper method

Tags: java, hashmap

I copy data from `HashMap<Class<? extends NXPersistentDataInt>, HashMap<Integer, ? extends NXPersistentDataInt>>` to another same type hashmap named **datamap**,and occured this error

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, AnalysisTaskDataobj> stringAnalysisTaskDataobjEntry : getTaskDataobjs().entrySet()) {
        HashMap<Class<? extends NXPersistentDataInt>, HashMap<Integer, ? extends NXPersistentDataInt>> hashMap = stringAnalysisTaskDataobjEntry.getValue().getDataMap();
        for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends NXPersistentDataInt>, HashMap<Integer, ? extends NXPersistentDataInt>> classHashMapEntry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            datamap.putIfAbsent(classHashMapEntry.getKey(), new HashMap<>());
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, ? extends NXPersistentDataInt> integerEntry : classHashMapEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                HashMap<Integer, ? extends NXPersistentDataInt> integerHashMap = datamap.get(classHashMapEntry.getKey());
                integerHashMap.put(integerEntry.getKey(), integerEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

at integerEntry.getValue()

IDE said :

```
put (Integer,capture<? extends com.cae_analysis.model.data.nx.NXPersistentDataInt>) in HashMap cannot be applied to (Integer,capture<? extends com.cae_analysis.model.data.nx.NXPersistentDataInt>)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: There is no way for the compiler to tell if `? extends NXPersistentDataInt` is the same thing as `? extends NXPersistentDataInt` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. This is not an IDE error...

Well, you can't do it. And the answer is right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777297/3798111

As you can see, you're violating some rules, think about something like this:

```
abstract class Super {
}

class Child1 extends Super {
}

class Child2 extends Super {
}

private static List<? extends Super> myList;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    myList.add(new Child1());
    myList.add(new Child2());
}
```

I have used a `List`, but it's the same for `Map` ok? When we use **capture of** we cannot know the right implementation of the `List` itself. So you would get an error if you add a, let's suppose, instance of `Child1` inside an `ArrayList<Child2>` and nor the compiler and the IDE can assure you're doing it right.

It's better explained in the link I have sent. But I will give you a workaround, but I really discourage it's usage... That sayd, hold it:

```
static abstract class Super {
    public String saySomething() {
        return "I'm Super";
    }
}

static class Child1 extends Super {
    @Override
    public String saySomething() {
        return "I'm Child1";
    }
}

static class Child2 extends Super {
    @Override
    public String saySomething() {
        return "I like coffee!";
    }
}

private static List<? extends Super> myList;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    myList = new ArrayList<>();
    addSomeData(myList, new Child1());
    addSomeData(myList, new Child2());

    myList.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.saySomething()));
}

public static void addSomeData(List someList, Object data) {
    someList.add(data);
}
```

Note that I didn't force the param `someList` type.

As you saw above, JAVA is tricky, so you can do a lot of sh* with it. I don't want you to do this with your `Map`, but in the real world as we know... sometimes... in a while... we do some sh*. So feel free to use (do not say you know me)