# Generics - How to transfer map to map with ? extends x?

Tags: java, generics

```
Map<String, ? extends MyClass> map;//instantiate and put values somewhere
Map<String, MyClass> map2; //instantiate and put values somewhere.
```

Given the maps above, how to transfer from `map` to `map2`, and from `map2` to `map` using `putAll()`, or achieve the `putAll()` effect?

If I know the Class is `InstanceClass`, can I somehow cast it to `Map<String, InstanceClass>map;`?

Comment: I must be missing something, because `map2.putAll(map)` seems like it would work. You can't do the converse, because it is not type safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Map<String, ? extends MyClass> map;//instantiate and put values
>   somewhere`

The wildcard expression `? extends MyClass` signifies a producer, meaning that you *can't* add objects to it because you do not know what type of object the value of the map currently holds. You can only read from it.

More info can be found in the following SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures).

Comment: If I know the Class is `InstanceClass`, can I somehow cast it to `Map<String, InstanceClass>map;`?

Comment: Use `? super MyClass` instead. This allows you to add any class whose super class is `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy them entry-wise. Here's an approach that uses `Map.forEach`:

```
map.forEach(map2::put);
```