# Why in java generics List<Integer> is a subtype of List<? extends Integer>?

Tags: java, generics

in java tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

it denotes that `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Integer>`, which I find counter-intuitive, because `? extends Integer` indicates any type that is `Integer` or subtype of `Integer`, what's the design considerations behind that?

quote:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

> The term `List<Number>` is more restrictive than `List<? extends Number>` because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses.

I'm also confused with `List<? super Number>` being subtype of `List<? super Integer>`.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by what part sounds counter intuitive to you, in your own description you state "... because `? extends Integer` denotes any type that is `Integer` ..." so do you understand as it is stated or do you not?

Comment: I visualize `Integer` as the top lid and `? extends Integer` being the bottle, then why `List<? extends Integer>` comes on top?

Comment: To abuse your visualization a bit doesn't some portion of the bottle have to overlap the lid? It's rare that you find a bottle with a lid that sits perfectly above the bottle, that would fall right off. Instead there has to be some lip for the lid to attach to right? Metaphors aside I was just trying to prod you some more since you seemed to have understood based on my reading of the question you posted, I couldn't speak to the design decisions myself. I'm probably more on your side, where I would think that any class `T` does not extend itself and so therefore doesn't match `? extends T`

Comment: Related https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Where exactly is your confusion? As you see from the answers, they are going all over the place - which indicates that your question as it is currently formulated is very broad. Too broad for the StackOverflow format, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why in java generics `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Integer>`?

Because otherwise you wouldn't be able to do things such as:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Integer> list2 = list1;
```

Personally, I would find the above resulting in an error to be the conter-intuitive scenario. When you have `List<? extends Integer>` all that's saying is that the `List` may contain `Integer`, some subtype of `Integer`<sup>1</sup>, or a mixture of `Integer`'s subtypes<sup>1</sup>. A `List<Integer>` certainly meets those requirements.

The argument for `List<? super Number>` being a subtype of `List<? super Integer>` is very similar. If that wasn't the case then you couldn't do the following:

```
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super Integer> list2 = list1;
```

All that `List<? super Integer>` means is the `List` is capable of consuming an object of type `Integer` or some supertype of `Integer`. A `List<? super Number>` meets those requirements.

Here are some links which may prove useful:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)
- [Difference between `<? super T>` and `<? extends T>` in Java [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)
- [How can I add to `List<? extends Number>` data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

I recommend browsing the linked/related sections of the above Q&As as well.

---

<sup>1. Saying "subtype of `Integer`" may be confusing since the class is `final` but hopefully it still makes sense.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that there is a supertype/subtype relationship at all, given [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) .  However, since there is, I can only hazard my own thoughts/guesses as to why it is allowed and why this way around.

EDIT TO ADD: Further checking, I shouldn't have been surprised, since the relationships are the same as Dog and Animal - ie.  `List<Animal>` **is** a subtype of `List<? extends Animal>`.

That being said, I imagine that it is to keep other references to these lists "safe".  For example, consider some possible cases using :

```
public class PositiveInteger extends Integer {
```

Then we could have

```
List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> myIntegers = listInteger;
List<PositiveInteger> listPositiveInteger = new ArrayList<>();
List<PositiveInteger> myPositives = listPositiveInteger;
```

Now, the idea of supertypes and subtypes is that we can assign subtype references to supertypes, but not vice-versa.  eg we can have :

```
Animal animal = myDog;
```

but not

```
Dog rex = someAnimal;
```

So let's apply that logic to our lists.

```
List<? extends Integer> positives = listInteger;
```

This is allowed as you said.  The important thing to note is that our existing `myIntegers` variable is safe - it will still only ever contain `Integer`s .

The only "danger" with this statement is that this allows `positives.get(0)` to potentially receive a negative Integer - but that's not really a danger at all (just a problem with our variable naming), since the language syntax here only refers to Integers, nothing about PositiveIntegers.  So far as the language is concerned, we could equally well have :

```
List<? extends Integer> positives = new ArrayList<NegativeIntegers>();
```

Now what about if we allowed :

```
List<Integer> integers = listPositiveInteger;
```

Now THIS bit of the system is safe - but what about our `myPositives` variable ???   All users of `myPositives` are perfectly entitled to expect to only ever receive PositiveIntegers, but there is nothing stopping us from having :

```
integers.add(-123);
```

Since that is the same List Object as `myPositives`, then we're adding -123 to that List - a much more dangerous prospect implicitly affecting the rest of the system.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing your point but `List<PositiveInteger> positives = listInteger;` would not be legal. In the linked short tutorial it specifically says the `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, but `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>` -- in order for example assignment to be legal `postivies` would have to be (_at minimal_) `List<? extends Integer>` to accept and assignment of `List<Integer>` or `List<PositiveInteger>`.

Comment: @BrandonBuck  Oops - you are quite right - I meant to type `List<? extends Integer>`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on `? super T` subtyping like this:

`<? super Number>` is a wildcard for `<Number>` or `<Serializable>` or `<Object>`

`<? super Integer>` is a wildcard for `<Integer>` or `<Number>` or `<Serializable>` or `<Object>`

`Integer` can be placed in all possible `<? super Number>` so `<? super Integer>` can be a `<? super Number>` (IS A relationship, so `<? super Number>` is a subtype of `<? super Integer>`)

`Number` can't be placed in all possible `<? super Integer>` (you can't put any `Number` where `Integer` is expected) so `<? super Number>` can't be `<? super Integer>`