# Java generics-in-an-instance-field design

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

Let's say I have `Node` class that is part of a graph. Each `Node` handles generic types `T` and `S`, so that we have `Node<T, S>`. Each `Node` can add inputs to itself from other Nodes via an `addInput` method.

```
class Node<T, S> {
  <T2, S2> void addInput(SomeUpdater<T2, S2> input) {
    // processes input
  }
}
```

One input `Node`'s `T` becomes the receiver `Node`'s `T2` in the `addInput` method.

Now let's say I want to store the inputs of each Node, within the Node. So:

```
class Node<T, S> {
  Map<String, NodeCache<T2, S2>> cache = new HashMap<>();

  <T2, S2> void addInput(SomeUpdater<T2, S2> input) {
    this.cache.put(thisIsOfTypeT2, thisIsOfTypeS2);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, because 1) `T2` and `S2` could be one of a handful of types, depending on which inputs are added, and the code above would require that all inputs have the same `T2, S2` types; 2) I would have to add `T2` and `S2` to the `Node` class, which I don't want to do.

Wildcards almost work fine:

```
class Node<T, S> {
  Map<String, NodeCache<?, ?>> cache = new HashMap<>();

  <T2, S2> void addInput(SomeUpdater<T2, S2> input) {
    this.cache.put("a string", new NodeCache<T2, S2>()); // compiler is fine
    this.cache.get("a string").get(thisIsOfTypeT2); // compiler nopes out of this one
  }
}
```

On the second `get`, I get `method NodeCache.get(CAP#1) is not applicable (argument mismatch; T2 cannot be converted to CAP#1)`. I'm familiar with this great answer on [wildcard generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures), so generally I think wildcards may be out(?).

Alternatively, I could do something like `Map<String, NodeCache<? extends SuperTypeA, ? extends SuperTypeB>> cache = new HashMap<>();`, but I run into the same problems. Ideally I'd even have `Map<String, NodeCache<? extends SuperTypeA, ? extends SuperTypeA & SuperTypeB>>`, but I don't think Java even supports multiple bounded types for wildcards.

Not sure how to proceed from here, though. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If every call to `addInput` can use different bindings for `T2` and `S2`, then the only thing they all have in common is that they are all `Object`, and that's also all you can safely know when extracting them from the cache, which means that generics cannot help you here, you should just declare it all as `Object`.

Comment: Editing the post to say that it could be possible to restrict inputs based on a few options, such that:

`Map<String, NodeCache<? extends A, ? extends A & B>> cache = new HashMap<>();`

Of course, `? extends A & B` is not possible, so might need another solution there.

Comment: While you are editing the post, can you explain what `T` and `S` have to do with anything?

Comment: Added; is that a bit more clear?