# `out Interface` in Kotlin function return type

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin with Spring Security. In the `UserDetails` interface in Spring, there is a method:

```java
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

When I let Intellij generate the implementation for this method in Kotlin, it generates this:

```kotlin
override fun getAuthorities(): MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority> {
  ...
}
```

What I don't understand is what the `out` here means. I know what it means when used with a generic type parameter, but here `GrantedAuthority` is an interface. I removed the `out` and everything still compiles fine.

What does the `out` means here and do I realy need it?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: @Slaw I've read that doc but have to admit I'm still confused. I understand how `out` works with generics and parameter types, but I still don't understand what it means in a non-generic return type.

Comment: It makes the `MutableCollection` a producer of `GrantedAuthority`. You can't add anything to it (i.e. the collection can't consume anything). This is exactly what `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` does in Java, by the way.

Comment: It Kotlin it may make more sense to have `Collection<GrantedAuthority>` since Kotlin distinguishes between `Collection` and `MutableCollection` (and the former is defined as `Collection<out E>`). IntelliJ most likely did what it did because `MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority>` is technically a better match to Java's `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>`.

Comment: @Slaw "This is exactly what `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` does in Java" - huh, I need to read up on that. Probably this also answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128815/implement-java-method-that-returns-collection-in-kotlin.

Comment: These Q&As focus on Java but are relevant to Kotlin as well: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397), [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202) and [How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975). Note that, as explained in the reference I linked in my first comment, Kotlin has what it calls [_declaration-site variance_](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) which Java does not have.

Comment: Its covariance, see https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47 this was one of the best explaination imo.