# Implement Java method that returns Collection in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin with Spring Security. When implementing this method:

```java
public interface UserDetails extends Serializable {
  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
  ...
}
```

I noticed Intellij generates this Kotlin code:

```kotlin
override fun getAuthorities(): MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority> { ... }
```

... which makes sense since `java.util.Collection` is mutable.

However, if I replaced the `MutableCollection` with `Collection` (which should be `kotlin.collections.Collection` IIRC), the code still compiles fine. This confuses me because `kotlin.collections.Collection` is a read-only interface that `MutableCollection` inherits from. It doesn't make sense that I can return an immutable collection for a method that's declared to return a mutable collection.

So my questions are:

1. Why does using `kotlin.collections.Collection` not cause an error here?
2. What's the correct Kotlin return type that's equivalent to `java.util.Collection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why does using `kotlin.collections.Collection` not cause an error here?

If you're not aware, the mutable and non-mutable collection interfaces in Kotlin both resolve to one interface in Java. So Kotlin's `Collection` and `MutableCollection` are both `java.util.Collection` in Java, Kotlin's `List` and `MutableList` are both `java.util.List` in Java, and so on.

Also, Kotlin has what it terms [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance). The Kotlin `Collection` interface is defined as `Collection<out E>` which means the interface is a producer of type `E`. As a consequence, having:

```kotlin
val col: Collection<GrantedAuthority> = ...
```

Is *nearly* the same as:

```kotlin
val col: MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority> = ...
```

I say nearly because, while `MutableCollection<out ...>` prevents anyone from adding any elements, it does not prevent one from mutating the collection entirely. For example, you could still call `clear()` on the collection.

---

> 2. What's the correct Kotlin return type that's equivalent to `java.util.Collection`?

Java does not have declaration-site variance. It also doesn't distinguish between mutable and non-mutable collections (at least not at the interface level).

This means that, technically, the best match of the following Java type:

```java
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>
```

Is the following Kotlin type:

```kotlin
MutableCollection<out GrantedAuthority>
```

Both types are mutable collection types and are defined to be *producers* of type `GrantedAuthority` (via `? extends` in Java and `out` in Kotlin). Neither type let's you add anything to the collection.

However, if your `getAuthorities()` method is supposed to return an *unmodifiable* collection (e.g. `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(collection)` in Java) then the more appropriate conversion from Java to Kotlin would be to use:

```kotlin
kotlin.collections.Collection<GrantedAuthority>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that this works is that `Collection` and `MutableCollection` are *both* equivalent to `java.util.Collection`.  You can see the full list of Java types that are mapped for Java interop [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types).

This works because the non-mutable collection interfaces aren't *actually* immutable (for that, you'd want the [Immutable Collections Library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable)), but they simply provide a read-only interface (as you note).  Since Java doesn't make this distinction, both have to be mapped to the same Java platform type.

> What's the correct Kotlin return type that's equivalent to `java.util.Collection`?

The correct return type depends on the interface you want to expose to your Kotlin clients.  If they shouldn't be mutating the returned collection, use `Collection`.  If you expect them to want to mutate it, use `MutableCollection`.  For your Java clients, it doesn't matter: they're equivalent.

Comment: "For your Java clients, it doesn't matter: they're equivalent." Not quite; due to variance the Java clients of `Collection<SomeClass>` see `java.util.Collection<? extends SomeClass>` and the Java clients of `MutableCollection<SomeClass>` see `java.util.Collection<SomeClass>`.