# Java best practice for casting generics

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
class ParametrizedObject<T> {...}
...
if (unknownObject instanceof ParametrizedObject) {
  ParametrizedObject casted = (ParametrizedObject) unknownObject;
}
```

This code triggers a rawtypes warning. Is there a way / best practice to avoid it ?

Note: The class `ParametrizedObject` is part of a framework, I can't change it.

Comment: You can use `ParametrizedObject<?> casted = (ParametrizedObject<?>) unknownObject;` if it can be any type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing with the casted object, but if you don't care about the type argument, a wildcard can be used to remove the warning:

```
if (unknownObject instanceof ParametrizedObject) {
    var casted = (ParametrizedObject<?>) unknownObject;
    ...
}
```

If you're doing something like setting some internal state that relies on the type argument, then it's not possible to safely do the cast due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), whereby all type parameters are replaced with `Object`:

```
class ParametrizedObject<T> {
    T data;

    void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

MyClass someObject = ...;
ParametrizedObject<?> casted = (ParametrizedObject<?>) unknownObject;
casted.setData(someObject);  // won't compile

MyClass someObject = ...;
ParametrizedObject<MyClass> casted = (ParametrizedObject<MyClass>) unknownObject;
casted.setData(someObject); // compiles but above cast generates a warning
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please elaborate, or give references to, other solutions that could be applicable depending on 'what i'm doing with the casted object' ?

Comment: @simo I added an example that doesn't work when using wildcards, specifically when the generic type acts as a _consumer_ (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super as related).

Comment: @simo - In addition to the link mentioned by M Anouti, you can also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776975/10819573 (which in turn points to the same link).